# How do I combine my backbonejs view with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

Backbonejs.org says

"— while very deliberately avoiding painting you into a corner by making any decisions that you're better equipped to make yourself."

So I have a BackBone view like this:

```
var LotsaToys= Backbone.View.extend({
el: '#CaveToy',
events: {
'click .slide': 'slideAnimal'
},
initialize: function (obj) {
    this.collection = new Yoyo(obj);
    this.render();
},
render: function () {
    this.collection.each(function (item) {
        this.renderToy(item);
    }, this);
},
renderBook: function (item) {
    var ToyView = new oneToy({
        model: item
    });
    this.$el.append(ToyView .render().el);
}
});
```

And simple Jquery code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var sudoSlider = $("#slider").sudoSlider({
        vertical: true,
        continuous: false
    });
});
```

Do I combine these to by simply adding the JQuery code in the slide function? 
(Simple Jquery image slider)

```
slideAnimal: function (event) {

    $(document).ready(function () {
    var sudoSlider = $("#slider").sudoSlider({
        vertical: true,
        continuous: false
      });
     }); 
    });
```

Im a noob, so please give me a explanation ,not sure what way is 'good practice' or what way would be better to implement..

Comment: What happened when you tried it? Hint: $(function() { ... }) is designed to be run once on page load. If `slideAnimal`'s purpose is to *do* something, then no, this isn't how you want to do it.

Comment: Well slide animals goal is to load on page load, do i put that in the initialize?

Comment: where do I draw the line of creating model etc, orjust using views?

Comment: To instantiate a jquery plugin, you simply need to make sure the DOM element on which you wish to invoke it is already in the DOM (the purpose of the document ready). Since you probably aren't trying to do DOM manipulations until after the DOM is ready, it's just a matter of making sure it happens on DOM elements that have already been appended into the DOM.

Comment: So I can control the order of the jquery plugins that load within the render method? as Eugene Glova suggested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need place it after `render`

```
render: function () {
    this.collection.each(function (item) {
        this.renderToy(item);
    }, this);
    this.slideAnimal();
},

slideAnimal: function() {
    this.$("#slider").sudoSlider({
        vertical: true,
        continuous: false
    });
}
```